# Why is WEKA not running from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, machine-learning, data-mining, classification, weka

I apologize, this seems like it is really simple but I can't seem to get it.

I've downloaded the Windows version of WEKA and installed it, but I can't seem to call it from the command line.

I've added a `WEKAHOME` environment variable, pointing to the directory containing `weka.jar`, and added that to my path with `/weka.jar` appended to it..

I am trying this command: `java weka.classifiers.j48.J48 -t %WEKAHOME%/data/iris.arff`

I then get the following error output.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weka/classifiers/j48/ J48 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   weka.classifiers.j48.J48
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class: weka.classifiers.j48.J48.  Program will exit.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you set the **java classpath** correctly?

Answer (score 3):

It's because of this `weka.classifiers.j48.J48`, that is an error in the Weka documentation, it should be: `weka.classifiers.trees.J48`

*(Note: the comments below are no longer relevant. The answer here works, and remember to set the classpath as Thomas Jungblut says below.)*

Comment: Maybe it's lowercase j. Let me check, one sec.

Comment: Here: `weka.classifiers.trees.J48`

Comment: There is a list of classifiers to choose from here: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html

Comment: If he doesn't set the classpath, he won't find the class. Add the jar with java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48.